# SharePoint O365 upload big file via CSOM

Tags: powershell, client-object-model, office-365, csom, onedrive-for-business

I am tring to upload large files (900 MB) to SP Online (actually the OneDrive Business) but seems to follow SP style.

Tried this via CSOM and powershell 70 MB are fine but when I try 900 MB a timeout happens after **3min**

**Error :**

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
>   At C:\scripts\BackupToCloud\BackupToCloud1.ps1:89 char:1
>   + $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

My upload part (of the script):

```
Foreach ($File in (dir $LocalBckupFolder))
{
    $StartAFile = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    Add-Content $log "$StartAFile :: Start Upload file: $File.name"
    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
    $Upload = $SPfolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    $ctx.Load($Upload)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $FinishAFile = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    Add-Content $log "$FinishAFile :: Done Upload file: $File.name"
}

$ctx.Dispose()
```

Try to use `$ctx.RequestTimeout = = 3600000;` or `$ctx.RequestTimeout = int.MaxValue;` but this is not recognized. 
As SharePoint Online doesn't offer the `Get-SPWebApplication` I can't set timeout there as I could on premise (no `Get-SPOWebApplication` available).

Also if large file upload via powershell to O365 (SP or OneDrive) should be done differently I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Is REST via PS a option? http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/04/15/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

Please see an example below:

```
$username = "admin@domain.onmicrosoft.com" 
$password = "Password" 
$url = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Test"
$path = "C:\temp\test";
$destination = $url + "/Shared Documents"; #lib partial url

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 

# the path here may need to change if you used e.g. C:\Lib.. 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

# connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.. 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$webclient.Headers["Cookie"] = $credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($url)

Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt 0} | ForEach-Object { 
    $webclient.UploadFile($destination + "/" + $_.Name, "PUT", $_.FullName); 
};
```

I have used PUT method to upload files

Comment: Does this work for large files?  And do you see any issue with converting this to C# to use in a Provider-hosted app?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out it will help you [Large file upload in SharePoint Online with CSOM PowerShell](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/large-file-upload-in-sharepoint-online-with-csom-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

If you could try writing a console application with CSOM, this could be achieved. Please refer to the Office Dev PnP [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/Upload-large-files-sample-app-for-SharePoint.md#sectionSection1).

PS: Sorry I am not sure about powershell.

Answer (score -6):

Find a different solution for files of that size, SharePoint cannot handle them.

Comment: The technical upper bound to file sizes is 2GB, SharePoint can handle them, but it might not be configured to accept files that large.

Comment: 2 GB is the limit of OneDrive Business and SP online (http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/sharepoint-online-software-boundaries-and-limits-HA102694293.aspx) "File upload limit  2 GB per file."

Comment: Technical limit and reality limit are two different things in this case. SharePoint is not designed to handle files of that size, use a different solution.

Comment: Is OneDrive business designed to handle large files? Also how large is too large? What is your suggestion? 50 MB, 100MB ???

Comment: 200MB is the maximum I will use for storing a file in SharePoint, after that there are just too many technical issues for it to be the best system.

Comment: You don't think SP Online is RBS offloading? your blanket statement is wrong, SharePoint can handle files of that size, the technical limit is 2GB, SP Online might be configured differently to set a lower threshold, just like on prem, but it is capable of handling a file that size.

Comment: Let me ask you this, does every single one of your users have a symmetrical gigabit connection? No? Then SharePoint isn't the answer for large file sharing.

Comment: Hi Aboda, I tried upload via script 200 MB but same timeout happens. (exact 3min) With now staying at your suggested 200 MB size you might be willing to answer my original question :-)

Comment: How fast is your internet? 200MB will still timeout at 3 minutes if you can't do it in 3 minutes. The 3 minute requirement is a server side timeout value. You need an actual upload speed of about 10Mbps to do that successfully.

Comment: I'm aware that my Internet upload is not fast enough to upload 200 MB in 3min. That's why my initial question about how to change the timeout on SP O365. So "Aboda" any proper answers?

Comment: Answer is you can't. It's done in IIS which you have no access to in o365. My original answer stands, SharePoint is not the solution start looking for other options. Also, can you please spell my username correctly?

Comment: REST API is the best way to upload big files in SharePoint.

Comment: If you dont want to go with REST API and if your customer ready to spend dollars,then this functionality can be achieved using 3rd party tools like Metalogix products.I have worked on similar scenario last year on SP 2013 on-prem  environment.